# How can I sort element in jsx in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an app that user can CRUD thread and main structure looks like this,

```js
export default function Dashboard(){
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <CreateBoard />
            <BoardList />
        </Fragment>
     )
}
```

`Dashboard` will be called  in `App.js`.
**BoardList**

```js
import { getBoards, deleteBoard } from "../../actions/boards"

export class BoardList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        boards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        getBoards: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteBoard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBoards();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2>Boards</h2>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Created</th>
                            <th>Updated</th>
                            <th />
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>  
                   // this sort does not work
                    {this.props.boards.length > 0 && this.props.boards.sort((boardA, boardB) => boardA.id < boardB.id)
                        .map(board => (
                            <tr key={board.id}>
                                <td>{board.id}</td>
                                <td>{board.author}</td>
                                <td>{board.title}</td>
                                <td>{board.created}</td>
                                <td>{board.updated}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button 
                                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                      onClick={this.props.deleteBoard.bind(this, board.id)}
                                      >
                                      Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    boards: state.boards.boards
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getBoards, deleteBoard})(BoardList)
```

Even though I sort it, it always sort my list descendant order(the newer post goes top). How can I fix it without rendering it every time?

Comment: Always add new board on top by `return [newBoard, ...state.boards]`

Comment: @JosephD. `return ( [newBoard, ...state.boards]` is it what you are talking about? where should I have to define `newBoard` ?

Comment: In your reducer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be cleaner to `sort` in the return function instead of the JSX. Also you need to clone the props into a new array that can be sorted.

```
  render() {
    const sortedBoard = [...this.props.boards].sort((boardA, boardB) => {
      return boardA.id > boardB.id;
    });
    const sortedRows = sortedBoard.map(board => {
      return (
        <tr key={board.id}>
          <td>{board.id}</td>
          <td>{board.author}</td>
          <td>{board.title}</td>
          <td>{board.created}</td>
          <td>{board.updated}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
              onClick={this.props.deleteBoard.bind(this, board.id)}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>Boards</h2>
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Author</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Created</th>
              <th>Updated</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.props.boards.length && { sortedRows }}</tbody>
        </table>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Note `sort` can be kind of tricky...

```
let a = [ '1', '2', '10', '3' ];
a.sort();
// [ '1', '10', '2', '3' ]

let b = [1, 2, 10, 3];
b.sort((x,y) => { return x-y });
// [ 1, 2, 3, 10 ]
```

Comment: It still does not sort the element by `id`. did you pull out sort and map outside of return for efficiency reason?

Comment: It's just easier to read. Is your `boardA.id` a string or an integer? Read my notes at the end.

Comment: It was number, I had to use `-` .